# Create a method that when I click on a picturebox it allows you to drag a clone image that the mouse can drag around the form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gs = this.CreateGraphics();
        Bitmap bimage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 200, 200);
        TextureBrush tb = new TextureBrush(bimage);
        gs.FillRectangle(tb, rect);
```

I don't get the image to move when I'm trying to drag it, this is to do with the mousedown method I think
I essentially want:
to be able to click down
drag the rectangle with the image in I have created
and then when the left button is released for the image to dissappear

Comment: Can you add some substance to your question and show us what you have tried?

Comment: Please give us context to your problem and show us a small code sample demonstrating your latest attempt and what is going wrong with it.  Also consider visiting the Help Center for this website to learn about the question format/details that we expect.

Comment: I would ideally have something similar to the Google homepage, where you can click down on the image then drag a faint/translucent clone around the screen

Comment: I've added what I have so far, you can essentially see that I'm creating a rectangle to contain an image, that follows the mouse, but I can't get it so that when you click and drag with the left mouse button it moves, and disappears when released

Comment: You need to create some control you can actually drag around. But if 'faint' means semi-transparent that will have to be another Form! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. It uses a `Form` that contains a `PictureBox` with an `Image`.

```
    Form form2 = new Form();
    Point mdown = Point.Empty;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mdown = e.Location;
        form2.BackgroundImage = pictureBox1.Image;
        form2.Opacity = 0.5f;
        form2.MaximizeBox = false;
        form2.ControlBox = false;
        form2.Text = "";
        form2.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        form2.Size = pictureBox1.Image.Size;
        form2.Show();
        Point pt = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);
        form2.Location = pt;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            form2.Location = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(
                       new Point(e.X -mdown.X, e.Y - mdown.Y ));
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: This is great cheers!!! However, the location of the image in relation to the mouse is dependent on where on the image I click to drag, is there a way to centralise the image/form onto the mouse?

Comment: Don't worry found it by changing the mouse move method to this 

if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point pt = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(-(form2.Width/2) + e.X, -(form2.Height/2) + e.Y));
                form2.Location = pt;
            }